# Codeigniter excel encoding issue

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I have downloaded php excel exporter library from http://phpexportxlsclass.googlecode.com/files/export-xls.class-v1.01.zip

It works fine if I run demo.php file independantly from the zip.

I have included export-xls.class.php file in libraries folder and called that library from controller

here is the code snippet

```
function export_to_excel() {

    require(APPPATH.'libraries/exportxls.php');

    $config['filename'] = 'test1.xls'; // The file name you want any resulting file to be called.
    $xls = new ExportXLS($config);

    $xls->addHeader("Test Spreadsheet");
    $xls->addHeader(null);
    $header = array("Name", "Age", "Height");
    $xls->addHeader($header);
    $row = array();
    $row[] = array('Jack', '24', '6ft');
    $row[] = array('Jim', '22', '5ft');
    $row[] = array('Jess', '54', '4ft');
    $row[] = array('Luke', '6', '2ft');
    $xls->addRow($row);
    $xls->sendFile();
}
```

but when I run my code using url `http://www.domain.com/controller/export_to_excel` then it will give me following excel file as an output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For windows support: add these line in private function `textFormat($row, $col, $data)`

```
iconv("UTF-8", "CP1252", $data);
```

see [this](https://code.google.com/p/phpexportxlsclass/wiki/PHPExportClassHOWTO) for more discussion on this issue.